# sql default time zone set problem facing please solve

Tags: sql, mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin, timezone

im trying to change the current timezone to Asia/Kolkata by using the following query in phpmyadmin. But its not working..

1st ..

```
set time_zone = '+5:30'
```

2nd .

```
SET `time_zone` = 'Asia/Kolkata'
```

3rd .

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+05:30';
```

4th.

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = "Asia/Kolkata";
```

But this not working showings this error

```
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Comment: The error seems quite obvious! Your account does not have the privilage to make that change

Answer (score 2):

Setting the global timezone does in fact require administrative privilege on the DBMS: it affects all the database's users, and could cause confusion to other software if it changes. Your error message makes it clear you don't have that privilege. It's considered a good practice to keep a DBMS's global timezone set to UTC.

Setting the session time zone (your first two examples) does not require privilege, as it affects only your session. Many applications set the time zone every time they connect to the DBMS, as this allows the current time zone setting to be handled as a user preference.

You didn't say whether your first two examples succeeded.  If `SET SESSION time_zone='Asia/Kolkata'` fails and `SET SESSION time_zone='+05:30'` succeeds, it means your DBMS's time zone tables have not been loaded by your system administrator. Ask that person to [read this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html). Be aware that many hosting providers refuse to load these tables, even though they're part of the standard configuration for MySQL and MariaDb.

(If both your first two examples failed, something else is wrong.)

For India-only apps, not having the time zone tables available isn't a problem because India does not use daylight time. But for many places, the offset between local time and UTC changes twice a year. The time zone tables implement those changes. For example, `America/Halifax` switches between `-03:00` in summer and `-04:00` in winter.